# I changed the normal direction, but it doesn't apply to Renderview

Tags: normals

[image]

I changed the normal direction using abnormal add-on.
When editing, the shadow changes well depending on the normal direction.
But after editing, if I look at the render view, it's the same as before changing the normal direction.
If I edit it again, the normal direction remains changed.
Why doesn't the shadow change even if I change the normal direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

modifier property - subdivision - advanced - use custom normals